# ClearOS transparent firewall and web proxy mode possible?

Tags: firewall, bridge, transparent-proxy, clearos

In other firewall software packages I have seen the ability and am hoping it is possible with ClearOS to put it in to transparent or bridged mode where the device sits physically between the client workstations and the internet router, but is the client workstation has the internet router address as it's gateway, not the clearos machine.

The client workstation would also not have to enter an http proxy address as that would be transparent.

Is this possible and how do you configure ClearOS this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found your answer, but yes, it is possible to configure ClearOS as a transparent proxy.

See [this manpage](http://www.clearcenter.com/support/documentation/clearos_enterprise_5.1/user_guide/web_proxy) for more information on web-proxy configuration.